# Why can't I name my Deerling "Summer Deer"?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-scarlet-violet

I'm currently on my first playthrough of *Pokémon Violet* and nicknaming every Pokémon I catch. I just caught a Summer Form Deerling and tried to name it "Summer Deer", but the game objected and said it wasn't allowed. (I tried "Sun Deer" instead and it accepted it.)

I can't think for the life of me why "Summer Deer" would be objectionable. Presumably there's some form of foreign-language [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) at play here, but what exactly is the game objecting to?

Comment: Try "Some Are Deer"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Generation VI onward, the Pokemon games use its own built-in profanity filter when entering in a [nickname](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nickname#Entering_nicknames) by the use of regular expressions. While I do not know what kind of processes go on in the profanity filter, I'm assuming many of the pre-determined [banned words](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_censored_words_(Generation_V))<sup>1</sup> from Generation V are included.

From the linked source, the word *merde* is in that list (a French swear word) and it's likely rejecting the proposed nickname because of "Sum**MER DE**er"

---

<sup>1</sup> Warning, lots of vulgar swear words

Comment: Yeah, that's gotta be it. I knew about the profanity filter but didn't think to check it myself before asking.

Comment: Good answer, bad feature. I want to be able to name my deer the way I want to! I guess there are many examples of normal names that won't work with this implementation. Banning all swear words of every language for every language causes these misunderstandings

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica Do you know your deer's gender? Buck is male deer, Doe is female. Maybe "Summer Doe"?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica This is a well-known issue with automated censorship known as the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). Unfortunately stakeholders keep insisting on automated censorship as a cost-effective token-effort to create safe environments for children.

Comment: @Philipp And Pokémon is rather notorious for this type of thing at this point. For a while back in 2011 when they originally implemented this type of filtering for online trading, it was actually impossible to trade certain Pokémon without giving them a nickname because they forgot to whitelist their own character names...

Comment: ADHD is in the list?

Comment: @Philipp Yep; it's a clbuttic problem in game/social software development.

Comment: @notmyrealname I'm sorry, WHAT?!